# Problem when maximizing window in C++

Tags: windows, winapi, window, maximize

My program needs to arbitrarily maximize any window on the current desktop. I achieve this by calling `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE)`, where hWnd is the `HWND` of the window I want to maximize. When that line of code executes, the window in question (here, Notepad) looks like this:

[image]

Everything seems fine, except for the fact that the window has not been positioned correctly, i.e. the window seems to be a few pixels to low, and the title bar does not look "squashed" like it should. Compared to how it should look when the maximize button is clicked, the problem is clearly visible:

[image]

Does anyone know why this behaviour occurs, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Telling the window to maximize itself might bypass some internal adjustments that the program makes when it maximizes via a system menu command. To emulate clicking on the maximize button, send it a [`SC_MAXIMIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Antoher way to use SetWindowPos(); For example you got HWND handleWnd;

```
RECT rcWnd;
GetWindowRect(handleWnd,&rcWnd);
SetWindowPos(handleWnd,WHND_TOP,rcWnd.left,rcWnd.top,(rcWnd.right-rcWnd.left),(rcWnd.bottom-rcWnd.top),SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

So you got your previous position, place window on top of Z and show