# How to vertically resize a window in code?

Tags: winapi

If I double click top border of a window it will resize vertically from top to the bottom of the desktop, but retain its width.

How do I do it in code?

Comment: I retagged as winapi. Good question.

Comment: There is no dedicated API exposed to invoke the Aero snap feature (see [Programatically invoke Snap/Aero maximize](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25833996/1889329)). It boils down to calling [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) with appropriate values. Unfortunately, this only approximates the effect. The window will not restore its lower edge when you start to drag the top border away from the edge. @MartynA: You clicked the title bar, not the top border then. The cursor changes its shape when you are over to border rather than the title bar.

Comment: Should'nt there be a way to send message (SendMessage) to resize a window in that way?

Comment: @IInspectable: "cursor changes its shape when you are over to border"  True, but dbl-clicking while the vertical sizing arrows are displayed does nothing on my machine.

Comment: You may try to SendInput a WinKey+Shift+Up though it's not entirely trivial due to WinKey usage.

Comment: @Tracer No, there is no such API

Answer (score 0):

Probably by just this code:

```
with Screen.MonitorFromWindow(Handle).WorkareaRect do
  SetBounds(Self.Left, Top, Self.Width, Height);
```

And the following alternative adds an animation:

```
Hide;
with Screen.MonitorFromWindow(Handle).WorkareaRect do
  SetBounds(Self.Left, Top, Self.Width, Height);
AnimateWindow(Handle, 200, AW_ACTIVATE or AW_VER_POSITIVE);
```

To be able to restore to the previous size, I thought `SetWindowPlacement` could be used, but I cannot make it work though.